# Extremal group elements from generators

Tags: group-theory

The elements of a group can be generated from generators.  What are the extremal cases called?

For example, the 7920 elements of [Mathieu group M11](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/html/M11.html) can be generated from GF(2) $10\times10$ matrices [$a$](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/atlasreps/M11f2.1) and [$b$](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/atlasreps/M11f2.2). The two extremal cases seem to be ababbbabababababbabababbaba and bbabbbabbbabbbabbababababb. In binary, 85283493 and 58160811.

What are these last holes called? For example, the 86775571046077562880 elements of [Janko group J4](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/html/J4.html) can be generated from reasonably-sized GF(2) $112\times112$ matrices [$a$](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/atlasreps/J4f2.1) and [$b$](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/atlasreps/J4f2.2). Is there a handy way of finding the extremal cases for J4 with these generators, or at least finding the expected length of these extremal cases?

Are there any non-small groups that have exceptionally efficient generators, where the extremal values are particularly small when compared to other groups of similar size?  Conversely, is there an exceptionally bad set of generators that has a far-out extremal hole?

Comment: In the special case of Coxeter groups (really, Coxeter presentations), they're called longest elements. I don't know if they have a name in wide use in general.

Comment: So basically I guess the question is something like "what is the behaviour of the diameter of a Cayley graph compared to its size (and the number of generators) ?".

Comment: Lama -- Yes. "What would be the last vertices generated for a Cayley graph with a given set of generators?" would be an equivalent question.